# Fast way to detect any changes of any element

Tags: javascript, html

I like to know if a attribute or content of any element in the DOM has changed. Mutation is deprecated and MutationObservable is not cross-browser. I was thinking to give any element a something like a check sum and validate it every 100ms against a hashtable, starting with the parent to the child nodes. Are there better solutions ?

```
<html data-checksum="981">
 <body data-checksum="541">
  <div data-checksum="354">
```

Comment: How about some library for this? Don't reinvent the wheel if possible.

Comment: what exactly is changing these nodes if not your own code?

Comment: The user by input. Can use events for this behavior and for my own code i can override some function but i'm not sure how many and which functions of the standards. I use typescript... I don't reinvent the wheel. Using Typescript. Because of this, i like to have some things different.

Comment: could look into the new DomElement `change` event